# Why there is no followers list?

Tags: python, instagram-api

Please guide me I call these api to get Instagram followers list but there is no data return.Why? Actually I have 1 follower. 
This is my code:

```
api_uri = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows'
params = {
    "access_token" : "6363126973.6c37f35.c7e39150a1d741e29d4ea329889b84b6",
    "scope": "follower_list"       
} 
req = requests.get(api_uri, params = params)    
print json.loads(req.text)
```

The result is:

```
{u'pagination': {}, u'meta': {u'code': 200}, u'data': []}
<Response [200]>
```

My Instagram Account capture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its probably cause you are in Sandbox mode, In sandbox mode you will only see your and and your sandbox user's info or posts. You also need `public_content` scope when authenticating. Once your app is reviewed and approve and live mode, you will see all users in API response.